# OpenCV JS working in Vanilla JS but not in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opencv

I have a html code where I am downloading opencv JS from the official website and importing into my vanilla JS HTML page. This HTML page does some business logics.
The code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Learning</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="input_video" height="480" width="640"></video>
    <canvas id="output_video" height="480" width="640"></canvas>

</body>
<!-- CALLING OPEN CV JAVASCRIPT -->
<script async
    src="/Frontend/src/assets/js/version_3/opencv.js"></script>

<script>
    async function playVideo() {

        // playing the video from webcam
        let video = document.getElementById("input_video"); //add a video tag with id videoElement
        video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
        video.play();

        // space for output
        let canvas = document.getElementById('output_video');

        // detecting ARUCO markers
        let arucoDictionary = new cv.Dictionary(cv.DICT_6X6_50);
        let parameters = new cv.DetectorParameters();
        // new vectors
        let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
        let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

        cap.read(src)
        cv.imshow("output_video", src)


        console.log(arucoDictionary)

        console.log('successful execution')
    };
    playVideo()
</script>

</html>
```

However, I need to convert this Vanilla JS into React library and I am having a hard time to achieve this.

This is what I tried in React JS. The output always says 'cv' not defined. I tried to import it using import but it's taking forever to import.

code below:

```html
import React, { useEffect, useRef, Component } from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

// import "Frontend\\src\\assets\\js\\version_3\\opencv.js"

const Video = () => {
  const playVideo = async () => {
    // playing the video from webcam
    let video = document.getElementById("input_video"); //add a video tag with id videoElement
    video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: false,
    });
    video.play();

    // space for output
    let canvas = document.getElementById("output_video");

    // detecting ARUCO markers
    let arucoDictionary = new cv.Dictionary(cv.DICT_6X6_50);
    let parameters = new cv.DetectorParameters();
    // new vectors
    let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
    let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

    cap.read(src);
    cv.imshow("output_video", src);

    console.log(arucoDictionary);

    console.log("successful execution");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <script
        src="\\Frontend\\src\\assets\\js\\version_3\\opencv.js"
        id="opencvjs"
        onload="main()"
      />

      <video id="input_video" height="480" width="640"></video>
      <canvas id="output_video" height="480" width="640"></canvas>
      {playVideo()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Video;
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv-react

Comment: Thanks @Eduards . I tried it but it's not working. I am not getting anything in the console. 
import React, { useEffect, useRef, Component } from "react";
import { useOpenCv, OpenCvProvider } from "opencv-react";
function MyComponent() {
  const data = useOpenCv()
  console.log(data)
  return <p>OpenCv React test</p>
}

const Video = () => {
  const onLoaded = (cv) => {
    console.log('opencv loaded', cv)
  }

  return (
    <OpenCvProvider onLoad={onLoaded} openCvPath='/opencv/opencv.js'>
      <MyComponent />
    </OpenCvProvider>
  )
}

export default Video;